TestNG test cases can't be run after Spring 4.1.5-RELEASE to 6.1.6 upgrade
Following spring version update from 4.1.5-RELEASE to 6.1.6, I am not able to run TestNG test case. Fixed all build issues due to deprecated APIs. But getting following error on running test case.
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class <Test_class_name>
    at org.testng.internal.objects.InstanceCreator.newInstance(InstanceCreator.java:41)
    at org.testng.ITestObjectFactory.newInstance(ITestObjectFactory.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:87)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:28)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:106)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:136)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:129)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:101)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:66)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:464)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:219)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:710)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:225)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:115)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1349)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1325)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1167)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.InstanceCreator.newInstance(InstanceCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createBootstrapContext(BootstrapUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.<init>(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:86)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.forDefaultResourceLocation(java.lang.ClassLoader)'
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:169)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:101)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.forDefaultResourceLocation(java.lang.ClassLoader)'
    at org.springframework.test.context.util.TestContextSpringFactoriesUtils.loadFactoryImplementations(TestContextSpringFactoriesUtils.java:69)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.<init>(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.<init>(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.<init>(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:195)
    ... 44 more

I have following dependencies in pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <name>project_name</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>description</description>
    <properties>
        <spring-version>6.1.6</spring-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.7.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.6</version>
            </dependency>       
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>   
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build scheduler automation</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.5</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.8.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>17</source>
                                <target>17</target>
                                <parameters>true</parameters>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.9.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.4</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.9</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>17</source>
                            <target>17</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

I have tried many ways to fix this, but I coulnd't.. Is this issue is due to missing of any needed jars? If some one has any idea on this, please let me know. TIA!

If you are using Spring Boot don't use version for spring dependencies, also I doubt those are your only dependencies as you are using TestNG. Please add your full pom.xml instead of snippets of it.

@M.Deinum :Please find the updated one!

I don't understand the Spring Boot starter dependency it totally doesn't make sense to have that, next to that it will also do dependency management and include incompatible versions. Your dependencies don't make sense either, you specified the versions in dependencyManagement so no need to include it here again. Tip instead of using the individual dependencies in the dependencyManagement use the Spring Framework BOM instead.
